# Docker container and FIPS mode enabled

Tags: docker, hana, fips

We're trying to get a SAP HanaExpress container running on a VM that has FIPS mode enabled, but it will not start up due to a FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE error. The VM is running CentOS 7, though I'm not sure that matters. I've read several articles/posts and it appears the running container does recognize that FIPS mode is enabled, but the service still doesn't work. Both of these checks work:

1. cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
2. sysctl crypto.fips_enabled

The container is running in privileged mode and the /etc/system-fips file is mounted into the container as well. Is there anything else I need to check to make this work or at least debug the issue? I have a feeling there's something small, and not HanaExpress specific, that I'm missing, but I just haven't found it yet.

Edit1: It looks like the issue is Docker and not the container. I finally found info that fips mode should be reported as active when you run the `docker info` command, but it wasn't showing up. CentOS 7 installs the 1.13.1 version, which appears to be too old, so I downloaded and installed 20.10.9. However, even following the instructions provided by docker, it's not reporting fips mode as active. If anyone else has had this issue and solved it, any advice would be great.

Comment: If you don't need FIPS enabled, then try this and see if it goes away. https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-fips-mode-on-centos-rhel-7/
then test if fips is enabled or not by running `sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep fips_enabled` and see if `sudo yum list installed | grep "dracut.fips"` shows dracut-fips is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

/proc/... files are READ-only files

If you don't need FIPS enabled, then try this and see if it goes away. https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-fips-mode-on-centos-rhel-7/
then test if fips is enabled or not by running `sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep fips_enabled` and see if `sudo yum list installed | grep "dracut.fips"` shows dracut-fips is installed or not.

I believe that if the HOST OS where you are running Docker container has this disabled, then you may not see this error

Comment: We did get permission to do so, so we did end up disabling FIPS mode. Not sure if that will be an appropriate long-term solution, but that's where things stand now.